# How do I shorten this error inside the textField?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a Textfield that would show an error if the password entered does not match with the confirm password. It does work, however, how do I shorten this out since I have to repeat these lines of codes to other textfield too.

```
 <TextField
            label="Password"          
            error={
              errors.length > 0 && (
                <ul>
                  {errors.map((err, index) => {
                    return <li key={index}>{err}</li>;
                  })}
                </ul>
              )
            }
            helperText={errors}
          />



<TextField
            type="password"
            id="standard2"
            value={confirmPassword}
            error={
              errors.length > 0 && (
                <ul>
                  {errors.map((err, index) => {
                    return <li key={index}>{err}</li>;
                  })}
                </ul>
              )
            }
            helperText={errors}
          />
```

How do I shorten that `errors.map lines` of coddes.

Comment: do you want it to be in a single component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `helperText` instead of `error` to show message error.

```
<TextField
  type="password"
  id="standard2"
  value={confirmPassword}
  error={errors.length > 0}
  helperText={
    <ul>
      {errors.map((err, index) => {
        return <li key={index}>{err}</li>;
      })}
    </ul>
  }
/>;
```

Comment: Thank you. This was way better. I have a question though, how can I remove the left indentation of li?

Comment: You can change padding-left of `ul` tag to do it

Answer (score 1):

In material-UI, error props of the TextField component will accept the only boolean values. And helperText props will accept node.
See here - https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/#textfield-api

You can simply create a component that will render errors messages with each field. For example

```js
import { TextField } from '@material-ui/core';

const ErrorMsgs = ({ errors }) => (
    <ul>
        {errors.map((err) => (
            <li key={err}>{err}</li>
        ))}
    </ul>
);

function Form() {
    return (
        <form>
            <TextField
                label="Password"
                error={errors.length > 0}
                helperText={<ErrorMsgs errors={errors} />}
            />
            <TextField
                label="Password"
                error={errors.length > 0}
                helperText={<ErrorMsgs errors={errors} />}
            />
        </form>
    );
}
```